# How to move the DataContext definition from code-behind to XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datacontext

I defined an object which contains properties in code-behind and, want to set the object to datacontext in xaml.

```
namespace WpfApplication4
{

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public EquipInfo equip1;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            equip1 = new EquipInfo();
            //  setting here works fine but i want to do in xaml
            //textBox1.DataContext = equip1; 
        }
    }
}
```

here's xaml code..

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=PIN}" Height="23" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="172,208,0,0" 
                 Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I answered to [the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16138690/200449)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the DataContext via XAML to a public property. blindmeis has given a good example on how to do this.

What you did in your Post was not setting the DataContext, but binding the Text Property of your Control to a Property of the window. This only works if a DataContext is set. Another way to do that, if you don't want to do MVVM (which I'd recommend, though), is referencing specific Elements in your Binding:

1.) Alter member to AutoProperty or similar

```
public EquipInfo equip1 {get;set;}
```

2.) Give your window a name

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Name="myWin"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
```

2.) Access Window Properties by instance name

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=myWin, Path=equip1.PIN}"/>
```

On a side note, it would **really** be better to use a [MVVM](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't know the object had to be property and Path could take dot notation. However, although EquipInfo inherits INotifyPropertyChanged interface, changing PIN property does not result in Text box, and I had to instantiate EquipInfo before InitializeComponent() to see binding works. Any problem?

Answer (score 1):

when you create your equipinfo class in codebehind why not setting the datacontext there?

nevertheless you can create a datacontext in xaml (you did not need the codebehind stuff then)

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=PIN}">
     <TextBox.DataContext>
         <local:equip1/>
      </TextBox.DataContext>
 </TextBox>
```

but please look at the MVVM pattern

Answer (score 1):

*When you create your equipinfo class in codebehind why not setting the datacontext there?*

The whole point of MVVM is to seperate UI from code behind using a viewmodel proxy. If you are going to reference the ui element to set its datacontext you might just as well reference it to set its value and forget about mvvm.