# Is any difference between the datacontext sets in code behind and xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am using the `DataGridComboBoxColumn`, and if I set the datacontext to the Window in XAML means the `ItemsSource` loaded fine in `combobox` column. If I set the datacontext to the window in code behind in `MainWindow` constructor after the `InitializeComponent()`, `Itemssource` not loaded in the combobox column.

Could you please share any suggestion on this ?

Code :

```
<Window.DataContext>
        <local:OrderInfoRepositiory/>
    </Window.DataContext>

<DataGrid Name="dataGrid1"
                  Width="308"
                  Height="200"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding OrderInfoCollection}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>

                <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="ComboBoxColumn"                                        
                                        Header="Position"
                                        ItemsSource="{Binding ComboItemSource}"
                                         />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding OrderID}" Header="Name" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

OrderInfoRepository definition:

```
public class OrderInfoRepositiory : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private ObservableCollection<string> comboitemSource;

        public ObservableCollection<string> ComboItemSource
        {
            get
            {
                return comboitemSource;
            }
            set
            {
                comboitemSource = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ComboItemSource");
            }
        }

        ObservableCollection<OrderInfo> orderCollection;
        public ObservableCollection<OrderInfo> OrderInfoCollection
        {
            get { return orderCollection; }
            set { orderCollection = value; RaisePropertyChanged("OrderInfoCollection"); }
        }        
        public OrderInfoRepositiory()
        {
            orderCollection = new ObservableCollection<OrderInfo>();
            OrderInfoCollection = GenerateOrders();

            ComboItemSource = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            ComboItemSource.Add("Germany");
            ComboItemSource.Add("Mexico");
            ComboItemSource.Add("Sweden");
            ComboItemSource.Add("France");
            ComboItemSource.Add("Spain");
            ComboItemSource.Add("Canada");
        }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code - `MainWindow` you tried so far ?

Comment: I have added the code in mainwindow.xaml, please help me. its urgent requirement.

Comment: The binding from Code behind not working ?

Comment: Try this in your code behind `ComboBoxColumn.ItemSource=YourDataScource`

Comment: No, if i set the datacontext to the window from code behind, combobox column itemssource not loaded. In the above code, i have set the datacontext to the window in XAML.

Comment: There is in theory no difference between assigning the `DataContext` value in XAML vs code-behind. People with urgent requests should be _especially_ careful to [present their question in a clear, answerable way](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem you are trying to fix.

Comment: @ElavarasanM this may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824600/databind-from-xaml-to-code-behind

Comment: is any option to set the itemssource to the combobox column without using the relativesource ?

Comment: Can you post the code behind of the xaml? You might be making a small mistake when you do it from the code

Comment: I would like to know if it's still urgent now? Or it has already been at deadline?

Comment: @ Sandeesh -  Please find the below code behind code.   'this.DataContext=new OrderInfoRepository()'. thats all in the mainwindow constructor after the InitializeComponent().

Comment: @ King King  - Its now urgent requirement in our side.

Answer (score -1):

There is a very small technical difference in setting the `DataContext` in xaml and the code behind.

When you define it in the xaml's code behind the UI will be initialized first and then the `DataContext` is initialized while if you define it in the xaml itself the `DataContext` is initialized while initializing the UI itself.

Unless you are missing the `PropertyChanged` notification in your `DataContext` there ***should not be any visible difference*** between defining the `DataContext` in xaml's code behind or xaml itself.

Comment: I have used the propertychanged. also by this http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/#comment-82716 one, i am able to acheive my requirement. Is any other way other than this ?

Comment: Can you post your class definition of `OrderInfoRepositiory`?