# How do I access a text bound to a dependency property in the view model?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I would like to access the dependency property bound to a text box in the view model.
In the view model I have the following code:

```
Answer _Answer = new Answer();
_Answer.GetValue(Answer.Deutsch1AnswerProperty);
Console.WriteLine(_Answer.Deutsch1Answer);
```

The dependency property is defined as follows:

```
public class Answer : DependencyObject
{
    // Ereignis
    public event EventHandler Deutsch1AnswerChanged;

    public static readonly DependencyProperty Deutsch1AnswerProperty;

    public String Deutsch1Answer
    {
        get { return (String)GetValue(Deutsch1AnswerProperty); }
        set { SetValue(Deutsch1AnswerProperty, value); }
    }

    public static void OnDeutsch1AnswerChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Answer _Answer = (Answer)sender;
        if (_Answer.Deutsch1AnswerChanged != null)
            _Answer.Deutsch1AnswerChanged(_Answer, null);
    }

    static Answer()
    {
        FrameworkPropertyMetadata meta = new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault);
        meta.PropertyChangedCallback = new PropertyChangedCallback(OnDeutsch1AnswerChanged);

        Deutsch1AnswerProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Deutsch1Answer", typeof(String), typeof(Answer), meta);
    }
}
```

In the MainWindow.Xaml I have the follwoing code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:Answer x:Key="_Answer" Deutsch1Answer=string.Empty />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid Definitions ...>
   <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Name="BoxDeutsch1" Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource _Answer}, Path=Deutsch1Answer}">
    </TextBox>
```

I cannot access the Text Property in the view model. Please help.

The view model looks like this:

```
public class VokabelViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Vokabel _Model;
    public VokabelViewModel(Vokabel model)
    {
        _Model = model;
    }

    private ICommand _boxDeutsch1_HitEnter;
    public ICommand BoxDeutsch1_HitEnter
    {
        get
        {
            return _boxDeutsch1_HitEnter ?? (_boxDeutsch1_HitEnter = new CommandHandler(() => MyActionBoxDeutsch1_HitEnter(), _canExecuteBoxDeutsch1_HitEnter));
        }
    }
    private bool _canExecuteBoxDeutsch1_HitEnter;
    public void MyActionBoxDeutsch1_HitEnter()
    {
        Answer _Answer = new Answer();
        _Answer.GetValue(Answer.Deutsch1AnswerProperty);
        _Model.TestVokabel(_Answer.Deutsch1Answer);
    }
```

Comment: You have a Resource in the XAML with an empty Deutsch1Answer, which is what is bound to your TextBox. I don't see where you set a DataContext to the "new Answer()" you did at the very top. You probably only want one or the other.

Comment: My DataContext is set to my ViewModel. How do I set the DataContext to new Answer()?
            this.DataContext = _VokabelViewModel;

Comment: Check out the top 2 answers here if you want to set DataContext in XAML: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590446/how-do-i-set-a-viewmodel-on-a-window-in-xaml-using-datacontext-property. I personally prefer to set it in code, however: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824600/databind-from-xaml-to-code-behind

Comment: Thanks - but I still dont have a solution for my problem. I have set my DataContext in the code to my viewmodel. The Class Answer is separate from my viewmodel because it needs to be a dependency object. I have also posted part of my view model above.

Comment: Try this. 1. *Define* an xmlns in your `<Window>` in XAML. e.g. `<Window ... xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:NAMESPACE.TO.ANSWER.VIEWMODEL" ...>` 2. *Replace* the `<Window.Resources>` with `<Window.DataContext><ViewModels:Answer /></Window.DataContext>`

Comment: Thanks - can I set multiple data contexts in the code behind as well?

Comment: DataContext can only be set once. If you need more data in your DataContext, you need to extend the viewmodel itself to represent more data.

Comment: OK understood. Then my real problem is how do I inherit both: INotifyPropertyChanged and DependencyObject for my Viewmodel?

Comment: You should not need to do both. The DO is superior to the alternative (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291518/inotifypropertychanged-vs-dependencyproperty-in-viewmodel). However if you still want both for some reason it's just `class Answer : DependencyObject, INotifyPropertyChanged {...}`.

Comment: Ah - thanks - now I feel stupid - I tried to inherit the Interface first - that didn't work. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access the Deutsch1Answer DependencyProperty in your ViewModel you should bind to it.
However I dont really see the point in why you've got the "Answer"-class.

If you want to bind the textboxs text to a property in your view model you should add an Answer property and bind it directly to the textbox.

In your ViewModel:

```
private string m_answer;

public string Answer
{
  get { return m_answer; }
  set 
    { 
      m_answer = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("Answer");
    }
}
```

In your View:

```
...
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Name="BoxDeutsch1" Text="{Binding Answer}">
...
```