# UWP dynamically added TextBlock-s are stacked

Tags: c#, uwp

Project build target: `Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (introduced v10.0.16299.0)`.

I am dynamically adding TextBlock-s:

```
    TextBlock headName = new TextBlock();
    headName.Text = h3.OuterHtml;
    headName.IsTextSelectionEnabled = true;
    headName.Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["TitleTextBlockStyle"];

    GridView.Children.Add(headName);
//...
        foreach (HtmlNode p in ps)
        {
            TextBlock pTag = new TextBlock();
            pTag.Text = p.InnerText;
            pTag.IsTextSelectionEnabled = true;
            pTag.FontSize = 16;
            pTag.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;

            GridView.Children.Add(pTag);
        }
```

Into xaml `Grid`:

```
<Grid   x:Name="GridView"
        Loaded="GridView_Loaded"
        Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
</Grid>
```

But text is stacked on each other. 
[image: Stacked TextBlock-s]
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal behavior for a `<Grid>`

*note: your `Grid` is not the `GridView` as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.GridView*

If you use a `StackPanel` the items get `stacked`... well... in the other form that is.

Eg:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="Stack"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
</StackPanel>
```

With code:

```
foreach (HtmlNode p in ps)
{
    //...
    Stack.Children.Add(pTag);
}
```

Having said that, I would advise you to look at binding, MVVM and xaml.

Your problem could be solved a more elegant way.

You also can use `Templates`, with them you can keep your UI fully XAML based, without the need to add children in code behind.

See:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/control-templates

Aditional info:

[Databind from XAML to code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824600/databind-from-xaml-to-code-behind)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/238bed43-e75a-472f-91c3-e16418b7948b/uwp-xaml-mvvm-binding-listbox-to-viewmodel-data?forum=wpdevelop