# ListBox Binding Issue

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-7, xaml, data-binding

I am facing issue with binding and I am following this example : http://listboxwthcheckboxes.codeplex.com/

Now the simple problem of the moment is that, the example has binded listbox succesfully to ViewModelSampleData.xaml(In the sampleData directory). But this binding only appears when I am viewing this in design view. When I run the app a new runtime data appears that is generated with code. This is counter productive in my case. My app can simple show the xaml data. I know it has to do something with these lines.

```
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
d:DataContext="{d:DesignData SampleData/ViewModelSampleData.xaml}"
```

Can you explain what can I do correct this? And give me a link or two that helps me understand what colons are used for and how can replace make this DataContext same that is used on Runtime.

Comment: Please absolute beginner in wp7... Thanks

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965853/how-to-have-designtime-data-in-winrt-xaml

Comment: Only One question what is the "local:" namespace for. I dont have any such in my windows phone pages. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `d:` namespace is only valid for design mode.

For the runtime mode you have to bind the `DataContext` without the `d:`:

```
 DataContext="{Binding ...}"
```

Comment: DataContext="{Binding SampleData/ViewModelSampleData.xaml}" This gives error. This is done in root tag of MainPage.xaml.

Comment: Can you add a few links that direct me to understand what is happening. I have followed read links but out of luck.

Comment: I am not sure if you can bind to the sample data directly. You could deserialize the sample data into an object and then bind to that object in code behind: DataContext = myDeserializedObject.

Comment: I am sure this is possible, but cant get to how?

Answer (score 0):

As you are a beginner, I suggest you to follow the straight forward approach for the data binding, instead of complex MVVM approach.

Check this link for the [Binding Data to ListBox through Code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2011/07/25/windows-phone-7-binding-data-to-listbox-through-code.aspx)

And this [ListBox databinding](http://3water.wordpress.com/2010/07/25/listbox-on-wp7/) also

Comment: Thankyou for these links but I have gone through those. I really want to bind data to XAML objects at the moment. Appreciate your help!

Comment: I could not disagree more. If he is a beginner, let him learn correctly from the beginning. Advising him to introduce architectural debt because he is new isn't a wise approach in my mind. He doesn't have to code it perfectly, but he should be encouraged to do it right, not wrong. And without MVVM, it's wrong.

Comment: @JerryNixon-MSFT I agree. +1 for your comment :)