# Windows 8 store app: How can I see sample data at design time?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

When I create a new windows 8 store application in Visual Studio 2012 with a splitted page, I see no sample data at design time at the start page ItemsPage.xaml.

But in the "underlying" page SplitPage.xaml, I see the sample data at design time.

I can see no substantial difference in the sample data generation.

The source code in ItemsPage.xaml is:

```
    <Page.Resources>

    <!-- Auflistung von Elementen, die von dieser Seite angezeigt werden -->
    <CollectionViewSource
        x:Name="itemsViewSource"
        Source="{Binding Items}"
        d:Source="{Binding AllGroupsDesignTime, Source={d:DesignInstance Type=data:SampleDataSource, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}}"/>
    </Page.Resources>
```

Any idea, how I can modify the code, so that I can see the data of the SampleDataSource?

Comment: I solved my problem with [How to have DesignTime data in WinRT XAML][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965853/how-to-have-designtime-data-in-winrt-xaml

Comment: No. Problem not solved. The problem seems to be a problem with my hard and software configuration. I have downloaded a working example from http://irisclasson.com/2013/02/03/a-simple-design-time-data-example-with-windows-store-applications-for-beginners/designtimedata3_1/ and the example doesn't work on my rig.

I see the realtime data but not the designtime data

Comment: did you ever get a resolution? it appears to be a bug when developing win8.0 apps on a win8.1 machine and specifically tied to the GridView (doesn't happen with ListView), but I cannot find anything to confirm this officially...