# How to have Xaml Designer use my app.config?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, configuration

I would like to have values of my database displayed in the datagrid of the xaml designer.

The datagrid has for context a viewModel that queries data in the database.

But the Xaml designer does not have access to my database configuration that is in the app.config.

ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myDbConnection"]  is null.

How to have the visual studio designer to use the default app.config file to have dome real values that appear in the xaml designer ?

**EDIT:**  I want to viewModel instance to be created by the designer so that it does supply some data from the database in the designer.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this approach:

```
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewModel:MyViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=False}"
```

More info is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303803/setting-design-time-datacontext-on-a-window-is-giving-a-compiler-error)

Comment: It's not what I want: I want to viewModel instance to be created by the designer so that it does supply some data from the database in the designer.