# How to do this.DataContext = this: in XAML....for eg<Window.DataContext> <local:MainWindow/></Window.DataContext>-->

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, datacontext

Although the result is same after compiling and running the code, I find out that there is a bit difference in design mode in defining the data context behind the XAML in .cs file like below

```js
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new MainViewModel();
        }   
    }
```

and doing in a xaml like this.

```html
 <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel/>
  </Window.DataContext>
```

The difference is during design mode in the display window while coding. When the code is in Xaml the view is nice and it shows the elements for eg. for `DataGrid` its shows the number of rows and column with value its value if its defined.

So, having said that I want to change below code in .cs file to

```js
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;          
        }
```

its equivalent in XAML. I tried with the below code

```html
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindow/>
    </Window.DataContext>
```

but it throw exception on Initialization. Can someone please help me with it. I am still new to WPF Databindings Data Context stuff.

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sets the `DataContext` to a new instance of `MainWindow` (which will in turn set the `DataContext` to a new instance and so on):

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindow/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

The equivalent of `this.DataContext = this` would be: `<Window ... DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">`.

You may also set the [design time DataContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303803/setting-design-time-datacontext-on-a-window-is-giving-a-compiler-error):

```
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:MainWindow, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}
```